# Tedious MSSQL driver, how to set transaction level to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, database, tedious

Are you able to specify transaction isolation level of READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT through the Tedious driver? I see the available isolation levels here: http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_beginTransaction

But I understand that the SNAPSHOT option in READ COMMITTED is not the same as setting the isolation level to SNAPSHOT. That said, I'm not seeing a way of setting the transaction level to this without appending it to every query that comes in, which I'd obviously rather not do.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Tedious.  However, in SQL Server READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isn't a transaction isolation level. READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is a database option for READ_COMMITTED.  So you would need to do something like:

```
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

and then

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm going to use the SNAPSHOT isolation level rather than append the first line you gave into every query I send.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of 2021 you seem to be able to do so. In this post I am referring to this version of the Node MSSQL driver:

```
"mssql": "^6.3.1"
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

There are five possible isolation levels when you import `'mssql/lib/isolationlevel'`:

```
module.exports = {
  READ_UNCOMMITTED: 0x01,
  READ_COMMITTED: 0x02,
  REPEATABLE_READ: 0x03,
  SERIALIZABLE: 0x04,
  SNAPSHOT: 0x05
}
```

Here is a possible way to to specify transaction isolation level of READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or any other isolation level through the Tedious driver for a connection, which you retrieve from a connection pool:

- You import the isolation level from `mssql/lib/isolationlevel`:

  `import { READ_UNCOMMITTED } from 'mssql/lib/isolationlevel'`
- We assume that you have a connection pool create something like this:

  `export const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig).connect();`
- Then after each connection retrieval you can set the isolation level by changing the configuration options of the connection:

  ```
    export async function executeSelectQuery(sqlQuery) {
        console.log('executeSelectQuery', sqlQuery)
        const conn = await createConn();
        conn.config.options.connectionIsolationLevel = READ_UNCOMMITTED
        const res = await conn.request().query(sqlQuery);
        return res ? res.recordset : [];
    }
  ```

I have used this code to verify, if indeed the isolation level was changed:

```
export async function executeSelectQuery(sqlQuery) {
    console.log('executeSelectQuery', sqlQuery)
    const conn = await createConn();
    conn.config.options.connectionIsolationLevel = READ_UNCOMMITTED
    const isolationLevelRes = await conn.request().query(`
    begin
        DBCC USEROPTIONS
    end
    `)
    console.log('isolationLevelRes after', isolationLevelRes.recordsets)
    const res = await conn.request().query(sqlQuery);
    return res ? res.recordset : [];
}
```

Indeed I could see this entry on the console:

[image]